# Unable to connect UISwitch to viewcontroller.swift

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, uiswitch

I created a new viewcontroller in my swift app to serve as a settings tab, however when I added UISwitches to the new viewcontroller I was no longer able to connect them to the viewcontroller.swift delegate.

Ben

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are trying to connect UISwitch to a delegate in a swift file?  Can you post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each view controller on the storyboard should have its own view controller swift file.  If your app has 2 screens, then you SHOULD have 2 swift files.

In this example I end up with two view controller swift files.

MainViewController.swift

SettingsViewController.swift

On the storyboard, click each view controller and on the right panel, select the identity inspector and make sure the the view controller is set to use the correct swift file.

[image]

[image]

In your view controller swift file add the following:-

```
@IBAction func doSwitch1(sender: UISwitch) {
    print(sender.on)
}
```

Go to the storyboard, click on the UISwitch.

On the right, select the "Connections inspector"

Drag from "Touch up inside" to the orange/red view controller icon on the ViewController. When you release it, it will display "doSwitch1". Click that.

[image: Connect the event]

[image: Choose the IBAction]

Comment: If this answered your question, please up vote and accept as the answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you had create a `.swift` class for your new `ViewController`, and assign it in `Storyboard`. If it is empty or not match, then you cannot drag the connection to that swift class.

[image]